# How enforce a range constraint on an InputField for a Number as a Manipulate control

Tags: manipulate

Enforcing a min/max range using a Slider is easy. Here it a Number is constrained to 0..1:

```
Manipulate[number, {{number, 0.3, "Number:"}, 0, 1, ControlType -> Slider}]
```

But when using an InputField control the min/max range seems to be ignored:

```
Manipulate[number, {{number, 0.3, "Number:"}, 0, 1, ControlType -> InputField}]
```

This enforce a Number but still does not enforce the min/max range:

```
Manipulate[number, {{number, 0.3, "Number:"}, 0, 1, InputField[#, Number, FieldSize -> 10] &}]
```

[image: Image showing Slider vs InputField in Manipulate for a Number]

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2520224).

Comment: Apologies for cross posting, I am continuing this discussion [on the Wolfram forum](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2520682).

Answer (score 4):

InputField does not have 'min/max' support but you can do:

```
Manipulate[number, 
  { {number, 0.3, "Number:"}
  , InputField[#, Number, ContinuousAction -> True] &
  , TrackingFunction :> Function[number = Clip[#, {0, 1}]]
  }
]
```

*edit: live restriction*

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this is only a partial solution. It does not restrict (live) in the input field, and AFAICT it even permits entry of non-numerical alpha characters (I didn't specify that requirement in my question, but using Number as I showed in my question does restrict the character entry)

Comment: @WebelITAustralia-upvoter take a look now, does it fit your needs?